# Setinha em menu com apenas CSS

Tags: css

Seta em baixo do menu drop down? Estou tentando fazer uma setinha no menu dropdown, então eu usei o seguinte código:

Porém o **z-index** (**outros objetos estão ficando em cima dele**) neste código não funciona e também eu queria que ele só aparecesso no **:hove**r (**quando passa o mouse em cima do botão**).

http://jsfiddle.net/Wagner/m0qyayf7/ (exemplo da setinha **balao2**)

estou querendo colocar neste layout:

https://coquus.xtechcommerce.com/forno-e-fogao

Segue o style que estou querendo implementar: (a classe que vou implementar se chama mesmo **dropdown**)

A solução tem que existir em CSS, não achei nenhuma questão parecida.

```
<style>
.dropdown:after {

content: "";

width: 0;
height: 0;

position: absolute;
z-index: 10;

border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 10px solid #000;

bottom: -10px;
left: 20%;
z-index: 15;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Não entendi, tem como montar um exemplo mostrando o que está dando errado?

Comment: O que está dando errado é simples, não é a setinha que está dando errado mas sim que ela tem que aparecer apenas quando está em :hover. Ou seja quando passar o mouse por cima. Além disto ela fica por baixo do :hover do outro <li> e o z-index: não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema do hover é simples, basta mesclar o uso de dois pseudo seletores: `:hover` e `:after`:

```
.dropdown:hover:after {
    /* css aqui */
}
```

Sobre o problema do `z-index`, se entendi direito, basta movê-lo para dentro de `.dropdown:hover`, que funciona, olha só (aproveitei para incrementar o `.dropdown` com espaçamento e flutuação para simular a exibição de vários `.dropdown`s em sequência):

```css
.dropdown{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown:hover {
    z-index: 15;
}

.dropdown:hover:after {

    content: "";

    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    position: absolute;

    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid red;

    bottom: -10px;
    left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
<div class="dropdown">Teste</div>
```

Comment: A entendi. E por que o z-index não funciona? Já tentei de tudo =/

Comment: @FelipeJorge Porque o `::after` está dentro da div, e não depois (apesar do nome).

Comment: @FelipeJorge Acho que não dá para descobrir o problema do `z-index` apenas com o código CSS e HTML que nos passou (ou então eu não entendi), entretanto coloquei um exemplo com os objetos um ao lado do outro, e não com outros objetos em cima do balão dropdown. Espero que isso ajude! Caso contrário, considere compartilhar um pouco mais do seu código! :)

Comment: @FelipeJorge Alterei minha resposta com uma alternativa para o `z-index`, colocando ele no `.dropdown:hover`. Acho que isso deve resolver.

Comment: @bfavaretto Agora acho que entendi um pouco melhor qual era o problema do `z-index`. Não tinha percebido que ele estava usando no `:after`, obrigado!

Comment: Eu testei, o que estava dando errado era que o elemento que estava em cima precisava de uma position: e também precisava de um z-index. Bom esta não é exatemente a resposta para minha pergunta, mas graças a você consegui resolver o problema. O elemento de baixo precisava de um LI