# Setinha em menu com CSS e que fique aparente quando clicada

Tags: css

Estou tentando fazer quase igual ao que foi descrito nesta outra pergunta: [Setinha em menu com apenas CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73493/setinha-em-menu-com-apenas-css).

Mas com uma pequena diferença: quando clicar no botão que fique marcado como selecionado. Que mostre que ela está naquela tal pagina, mas junto com a seta em destaque.

---

[image]

E como ta agora, e eu quero que fique nessa outra imagem, que a seta fica no meio, e eu não como fazer isso.

### Código

```
nav a{ 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    position: relative;
} 

nav a:hover:before{ 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-top-color: #888888; 
    content: ""; 
    bottom: -20px; 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: Você fez o MENU, agora só falta mostrar a seta quando estiver na página daquele Link no MENU ?

Comment: isso, mas não consigo

Comment: queria fazer com que a seta ficasse em destaque quando estivesse em uma pagina

Comment: Qual é o código da setinha ? Coloca ele aí.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você tem que ter um CSS desse:

```
.dropdown.current {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 20%;
}
```

Depois em cada linha do LINK você coloca na `tag` do `class="dropdown"` um `if` para verificar se está nessa página, se sim você aplica a `class='current'`.

Está usando alguma linguagem server-side, tipo PHP, ou só HTML, CSS e JS ?

O `if` pode ser feito em um código JS ou PHP.

---

Nesse seu *CSS* abaixo coloque as propriedades:

```
left: 0; 
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

Assim:

```
nav a:hover:before{ 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-top-color: #888888; 
    content: ""; 
    bottom: -20px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Só HTML  e CSS, não estou usando mais nada.

Comment: é uma muita coisa, e já tudo no site que eu to fazendo

Comment: e tbm e já já tenho que sair

Comment: agora não da, faço isso quando chegar

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: vc tem um que seja do jeito que eu quero?

Comment: Já consegui arrumar, obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta como faço pra centralizar essa SETA em um retângulo ou quadrado?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, vc pode explicar melhor?

Comment: pera ai to procurando. `
nav a{
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
 color: #ffffff;
 position: relative;
}

nav a:hover:before{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: #888888;
 content: "";
 bottom: -20px;
 position: absolute;
}`

Comment: eu não sei colocar código aqui

Comment: Sem problemas, editei meu post. Veja agora.

Comment: Agora foi, muito obrigado